# Change height of popup window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I click on my extension icon a popup windows appears, but the problem I'm facing is that the popup windows height is too large so it gets below my taskbar. Is there anyway to set the height of the popup window?

I have tried with declaring height and width in a css file by the body tag. But only the width of the window changes. I have also tried with making an iframe, but the popup window only gets blank.

Comment: Normally the popup will be as high as your content...

Answer (score 12):

Add the following at the beginning of your popup page to replace the `<html>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Good luck!

Comment: \<!DOCTYPE html\>  - remember this should be no slash in your page, i added this slash because stackoverflow will filter out the any strings encapsulated by <>

Comment: Wow, I never would've guessed that would solve a problem with the window size. You are my hero.

Comment: it solved my problem which is different than question asked here. it was issue when reducing height of popup dynamically, it was staying at old height with white space filling up extra height. DOCTYPE matters !

Answer (score 6):

You can set height and width of your popup window by using window.resizeTo(preferedWidth, preferedHeight) function. If you want to set this inside a popup window not from parent window than self.resizeTo(preferedWidth, preferedHeight); will do the job for you.

Better suggestion is to keep your content inside a div for example div with id 'content' so you can use this for popup window.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeMe()
{
    height = document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight;
    width  = document.getElementById("content").offsetWidth;
    self.resizeTo(width+20, height+100);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="resizeMe();">
```

This should be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: i've used +20 for width as i want browser to be wider by 20 pixel than my content and +100 for height as i want it higher by 100 pixel to my content, you can have your own custom width and heights,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
       max-height: 300px;
    }
</style>

or just,

<style type="text/css">
    body {
       height: 300px;
    }
</style>
```

In the `<head>` tag of your popup.html.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
chrome.windows.create({
    type: 'popup', 
    width: 400, 
    height: 300, 
},)
```